# Different results for the very same method

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape and parse some data from one web page. The problem is that the script act's different after several attempts.

```
import mLib
import requests
import urlparse

URL = 'http://www.distrelec.sk/'

class base():

    def __init__(self):
        self.soup = mLib.getSoup(URL)

    def get_info(self,url):

        soup = mLib.getSoup(url)
        up_left_table_outer = soup.find('table',class_='validate-checkbox-group')

        for row_outer in up_left_table_outer.find_all('tr'):
            key_value = row_outer.find_all('td')
            key = key_value[0].label.text
            value = key_value[1].span.text
            yield key,value


bs = base()
for i in range(1,20):
    print dict(bs.get_info('http://www.distrelec.sk/sk/socket-mm-cerna-multi-contact-lb4-black/p/11034944?q=*&filter_Buyable=1&filter_Category3=Laborat%C3%B3rne+konektory&page=1&origPageSize=10&simi=99.8'))
```

Here is a part of the output (it should be the same each line). As you can see, the key Contact B and Contact A are sometimes different. The problem is probably that there is more than one line of text on the web page:

```
{u'Barva': u'\u010cern\xe1', u'Jmenovit\xe9 nap\u011bt\xed': u'30 VAC 60 VDC, 20 A', u'Contact A': u'Z\xe1suvka', u'Velikost': u'\xf8 4 mm', u'Contact B': u'M6'}
{u'Barva': u'\u010cern\xe1', u'Jmenovit\xe9 nap\u011bt\xed': u'30 VAC 60 VDC, 20 A', u'Contact A': u'\xf8 4 mm', u'Velikost': u'\xf8 4 mm', u'Contact B': u'P\xe1jen\xed'}
{u'Barva': u'\u010cern\xe1', u'Jmenovit\xe9 nap\u011bt\xed': u'30 VAC 60 VDC, 20 A', u'Contact A': u'Z\xe1suvka', u'Velikost': u'\xf8 4 mm', u'Contact B': u'M6'}
{u'Barva': u'\u010cern\xe1', u'Jmenovit\xe9 nap\u011bt\xed': u'30 VAC 60 VDC, 20 A', u'Contact A': u'\xf8 4 mm', u'Velikost': u'\xf8 4 mm', u'Contact B': u'M6'}
{u'Barva': u'\u010cern\xe1', u'Jmenovit\xe9 nap\u011bt\xed': u'30 VAC 60 VDC, 20 A', u'Contact A': u'Z\xe1suvka', u'Velikost': u'\xf8 4 mm', u'Contact B': u'M6'}
{u'Barva': u'\u010cern\xe1', u'Jmenovit\xe9 nap\u011bt\xed': u'30 VAC 60 VDC, 20 A', u'Contact A': u'Z\xe1suvka', u'Velikost': u'\xf8 4 mm', u'Contact B': u'M6'}
{u'Barva': u'\u010cern\xe1', u'Jmenovit\xe9 nap\u011bt\xed': u'30 VAC 60 VDC, 20 A', u'Contact A': u'\xf8 4 mm', u'Velikost': u'\xf8 4 mm', u'Contact B': u'P\xe1jen\xed'}
{u'Barva': u'\u010cern\xe1', u'Jmenovit\xe9 nap\u011bt\xed': u'30 VAC 60 VDC, 20 A', u'Contact A': u'\xf8 4 mm', u'Velikost': u'\xf8 4 mm', u'Contact B': u'M6'}
```

Do you have any idea where is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps the contents of the URL are changing? EDIT: Just checked; they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the URL are changing. [Try refreshing it a few times](http://www.distrelec.sk/sk/socket-mm-cerna-multi-contact-lb4-black/p/11034944?q=*&filter_Buyable=1&filter_Category3=Laborat%C3%B3rne%20konektory&page=1&origPageSize=10&simi=99.8).

Compare this:

[image: <code>Zásuvka</code> and <code>Pájení</code> are first]

With this:

[image: <code>ø 4 mm</code> and <code>M6</code> are first]

Each Contact changes independently, so there are four different combinations in this case.